# xcode 4.3 - UITextField - Custom Keyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I have two TextFields and I am designing a custom keyboard for ipad.

How can I dissmis system keyboard and let mine apear.

how can I know that the user is activating which TextField?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the delegate to textfields to your view controller instance you have to implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

and if you return YES it will open the system keyboard, if you return NO it won't.

Before returning NO, of course, you can show your view.

You will know which textField is "pressed" using tag property.